# Why does visual studio provide two implementations for the IEnumerable interface

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ienumerable

By default, if i create a class that uses the IEnumerable interface, and allow visual studio provide the default implementations, it creates two. An explicit implementation of the interface, and a normal 'override' of the interface method?

Whats going on here? the only use case i have encountered for explicit interface implementations is to make use of two interfaces with the same method signature, but that doesnt appear to be the case here.

Comment: `IEnumerable` and `IEnumerable<T>` are distinct interfaces.  We'll never get completely rid of .NET 1.x

Answer (score 2):

This is because you get two interfaces and two different methods. `IEnumerable<T>` implements `IEnumerable` (the non-generic version), and each of those requires `GetEnumerator` to be implemented. Typically `IEnumerable` is implemented explicitly, so most users of the class (those not explicitly typing it as `IEnumerable`, will get the preferred `IEnumerable<T>` implementation when calling `GetEnumerator`.

I suspect this design was chosen (`IEnumerable<T>` being an `IEnumerable`) to avoid compatibility problems with older code not being aware of generics.